# Eclipse IDE won't resolve classname automatically

Tags: eclipse, import, jar

I have a Jar, which I have included in my project.

When I import a class from this project by specializing the full name as `org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.editor.ICellEditor` the class is imported well.

Writing `ICellEditor` and doing "Organize Imports" doesn't work.
Doing "Open Type" and typing `ICellEditor` finds the right class, so Eclipse is aware of this JAR amd class; but does not show the class on "Organize Imports".

Do someone know what the reason could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your jar path is included in the **CLASSPATH**. When you give fully qualified name as shown below **CLASSPATH** is not required. (as you give the complete path explicitly).

```
org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.editor.ICellEditor
```

So if you want your import in eclipse to work properly :

So either put this jar in the existing jar directory or make sure that the jar path is added in **CLASSPATH**.